# Pythonically adding keys to a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, ordereddictionary

I want to add a key with a count one and increment it everytime it increases, this is a classic operation. This is my regular code.

```
d = OrderedDict()
for i, v in enumerate(s):
   if v not in d:
      d[v] = 1
   else:
      d[v] += 1
```

How can I do this with 1 line of code using `setdefault` and not `collections. Counter`
Like if this was a list then I could have done,

`d.setdefault(v, []).append()`

Is there a way to do a similar thing with integer addition.

Comment: What's wrong with `collections.Counter`? And `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: What is `s`? Do you mean `enumerate(d)`?

Comment: How about using defaultdict?

Comment: You can't do this using `setdefault()` because it returns the object that has been set and since integers are immutable changing them will not change the original object, instead it will creates a new one. Now one workaround is to use what @J. Snow proposed or creating your own dictionary that performs like `Orderdict` and `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
d[v] = d.get(v, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use an ordered counter. If you are happy to import `OrderedDict`, there's no reason, in my opinion, you should avoid `Counter`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

s = [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]

d = OrderedCounter(s)

print(d)

OrderedCounter({3: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1})
```

Note in Python 3.7+ you can just use `Counter` since dictionaries are insertion-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to go for the oneliner and are allowed to use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 4, 7, 3]

d = {key: len(list(items)) for key, items in itertools.groupby(sorted(s))}
```